# What is cost of context switching to secure mode (arm trustzone)

Tags: security, operating-system, arm, context-switch, trustzone

I am trying to understand the cost of switching back and forth between trusted (secure) and non-secure modes in arm.

What exactly needs to happen when moving from non-secure to secure world? I know the ns bit needs to be set (based on some special instruction?), the page tables need to be flushed and updated (?), the processor caches flushed and updated. Anything else that needs to happen?

Processor caches: Are they caches segmented and shared or is the whole cache used for each mode? That determines the cost of the switch.

RAM: This must be 'partitioned' and used by both modes. So addressing is just an offset into the 'partition'. Is this right?

What is different about this from a user space to kernel mode switch or a process to process switch in user space?

Is there anything in moving from non-secure to secure modes that would make it more expensive than the regular process context switch?

Are there any articles that explain what exactly happens?

EDIT: Based on a reply below, I am looking to understand what exactly happens when a process switches from non-secure mode to a secure mode (trust zone) on an arm processor.

Comment: Can you narrow your question to a specific one so you increase your chance of getting an answer ?

Comment: @Tony, I am looking to understand what exactly happens when a process switches from non-secure mode to a secure mode (trust zone) on an arm processor. Are you looking for more specifics?

Comment: Now it's better, I don't know the specific architecture. But when you trigger a system call, it is being executed in the context of the current process, in privileged mode. There's no switching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What exactly needs to happen when moving from non-secure to secure world?

TL-DR; the minimum is to save/restore all  CPU registers that are needed by the secure world and change the NS bits.  Normally, R0-R14 as well as current mode, and banked LR and SP (aborts, interrupts, etc) are in this register group.  Everything else depends on your security model.

---

First off, there are many different models that can be used in TrustZone; TrustZone is a tool not a solution.  The most basic model is a library with API where some secure data is stored (ie decryption keys) to process by an external source (some DRM download from the 'normal world' space).  I assume you don't mean this.

An OS can be pre-emptible and non-premptible.  If you have two OSes in both worlds, then how control is relinquished, resources shared and security assets protected will all come into play on a world switch.

In many cases, the caches and TLB are world aware.  Devices may also be world aware and designed with the intent that context is built into the device.  This is not to say that some system might have information leaked in some way.

- [Meltdown (2017)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meltdown_(security_vulnerability))
- [Specter (2017)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectre_(security_vulnerability))
- [Hyperthreading exploit (2004)](http://www.daemonology.net/papers/htt.pdf)

If you are really concerned about this type of attack, it may be appropriate to mark the secure world memory as non-cached that needs to be protected.  In many ARM systems, the L1/L2 and TLB cache are unified between worlds and can provide a side channel attack.

TrustZone as implmented on many ARM devices comes with a GIC which can run FIQ in the secure world and masking of FIQ can be prevented in the normal world.  Many GIC features are banked between worlds allowing both OSes to use it without 'context switch' information.  Ie, the NS bit will automatically change the accessed GIC features based on the state of the NS bit (so it has the context stored in the device).  Many other vendor specific devices are designed to behave this way.

If both worlds use NEON/VFP, then you need to save/restore these registers on a world switch as well.  For pre-emption you may need to hook into the OS secure scheduler to allow and normal world interrupt to pre-empt the secure world main line (obviously this depends on assets you are trying to protect; if you allow this the secure mainline has a DOS vector).

If there are glitches in devices, then you may need to save/restore device state.  If the normal world is restricted from using FIQ mode, it is still needed to at least clear the SP_fiq and LR_fiq when going to the normal world (and restore the secure value the other way).  Some of these registers are difficult to save/restore as you must switch modes which can itself be a security risk if care is not taken.

> RAM: This must be 'partitioned' and used by both modes. So addressing is just an offset into the 'partition'. Is this right?

Secure boot will partition memory based on the 'NS bit'.  The physical memory will be visible or not based on the partition manager device logic which can often be locked at boot.  Ie, if non-visible it is a bus error like any non-existent memory.  There is no 'switch' beside the NS bit.

> Is there anything in moving from non-secure to secure modes that would make it more expensive than the regular process context switch?

Yes a normal switch is only for a 'mode'.  A world is for all ARM modes and so all banked registers must be switched.  Depending on the system the TLB and cache would not normally need to be switched.

---

Related:

- [How to introspect normal world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288422/how-to-introspect-normal-world-from-secure-world-using-trustzone)
- [TrustZone monitor mode switch design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41234780/arm-trustzone-monitor-mode-switch-design)
- [Preventing memory access from the normal world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32458599/use-arm-trustzone-to-prevent-access-to-memory-region-from-non-secure-world)
- [How is a TrustZone OS secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561144/how-is-an-arm-trustzone-secure-os-secure)
- [TrustZone scheduler in secure/non-secure OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659472/arm-trustzone-behaviour-of-the-scheduler-in-secure-and-non-secure-os)
- [IMX53 and TrustZone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29533692/i-mx53-qsb-and-arm-trustzone)
- [ARM Trusted firmware](https://github.com/ARM-software/arm-trusted-firmware) on github
- [TrustZone Whitepaper](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.prd29-genc-009492c/PRD29-GENC-009492C_trustzone_security_whitepaper.pdf)